# WSO2 grant type client_credentials is alway required

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 with API Manager 2.1.0
I add an Application in the API Store, in the Production Keys I populate the Callback URL and disable all Grant Types except Code.
When I try to Generate Keys I get the error,
"Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey".

When I start again, and leave all the Grant Types enabled, I can Generate the Keys OK. Then I try disabling all the type except the Code. Click Update (in case it's needed). Then when I check the database IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN the grant type for the token is still set to "client_credentials".

Do I need to ALWAYS have the Client Credentials enabled?
In the database IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN, I've only ever seen either password or client_credentials at the grant type, should the other type appear there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating a new token from the APIM Store (for the application), a client_credentials profile (application level token) is used. If you disable the "client_credentials" profile on the API, you won't be able to generate a token from the API Store test console (only using OAuth code profile)